# How to prevent JBoss AS 7.x to deploy Web Services contained in a web app dependency

Tags: java, web-services, deployment, jboss7.x

We have a web app with a .jar in our WEB-INF/lib that contains some annotated Web Services.
JBoss try to deploy the Web Services defined in the .jar but we want only to use the classes as normal java API.

There is a way to prevent JBoss to deploy the Web Services?

We cannot modify the .jar and we have some RESTful services in our web app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general the shared libs folder of your application should contain only utility classes without any component-declaring annotations (such EJB3 or JAX-RS), as it can have unintended and undesirable consequences on the deployment process.

To sort this problem out in jboss 7.x you have to remove the jars from WEB-INF/lib (or lib if you have an EAR). Third party libraries have to be installed as modules https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/MODULES/Defining+a+module.

Then you have to declare the module in the MANIFEST of your war in the *Dependencies* list.

Hope it helps,
Fabrizio

Comment: Thank you Fabrizio, this solution is working, just another question, the dependency in the manifest is standard or JBoss specific? I can use it like org.hibernate and it will work in any OSGi container or for other container I must change it to the jar name?

Comment: Teg, I believe the _Dependencies_ property is jboss specific. I am not 100% sure of that. I suppose you have to change some configuration to run you application in an OSGI container. Cheers